# groovy:LinkedHash: missing property

Tags: groovy

I'm struggling to remove key 'customerNumber' from sub-arrays allAddresses and allPersons. my requirement is that in the below payload key customerNumber should only appear in the parent array CustomerMaster. all other appearances of customerNumber should be deleted.

with the below code I get error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: allAddresses for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry. To my surprise the code works when the key CustomerMaster is an array. I dont understand why it fails if the customer is not an array

```
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;
import groovy.json.*
def Message removeCustomerNumber(Message message) {
def body = message.getBody(String)
//def body = message.getBody(String.class);
body=body.toString();
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body)
json.CustomerMaster.each{
//    if (it.allAddresses.metaClass.respondsTo('each')){
//    if(it.metaClass.hasProperty(it, 'allAddresses')){
it.allAddresses.each{  
     it.remove('customerNumber')
                    }
 //     }
 //   }     
 }
def out= JsonOutput.toJson(json);
//out = JsonOutput.prettyPrint()
message.setBody(out);
return message;
}
```

in other words when the CustomerMaster is an collection, I have no issue. I tried checking with hasProperty() and respondsTo() with out success

payload:

```
{
    "CustomerMaster": {
        "activitySector": "01",
        "cognosCode": "ES001",
        "companyName1": "SANIPLAST SOL. SOSTEN. DEL AGUA SL",
        "companyName2": "ALIAXIS IBERIA S.A.U.",
        "creditControlArea": "ES01",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "customerNumber": "0000100001",
        "allPersons": [
            {
                "birthday": "00000000",
                "cognosCode": "ES001",
                "contactId": "0000000308",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "jobTitle": "ENCARGADO COBROS",
                "language": "ES",
                "lastName": "EDUARDO JIMENEZ"
            },
            {
                "birthday": "20210419",
                "cognosCode": "ES001",
                "contactId": "0000000475",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "email1": "FACTURASPDF.SNPT@ABAST.ES",
                "jobTitle": "ENVÍO FACTURACIÓN",
                "language": "ES",
                "lastName": "FACTURACION"
            },
            {
                "birthday": "00000000",
                "cognosCode": "ES001",
                "contactId": "0000000036",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "jobTitle": "REPRESENTANTE LEGAL",
                "language": "ES",
                "lastName": "D. JULIO ESTEBAN SALGADO"
            }
        ],
        "allAddresses": [
            {
                "StateOrProvince": "MERES-SIERO",
                "city": "MERES-SIERO",
                "countryCode": "ES",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "fax": "985793802",
                "id": "0000372156",
                "name": "SANIPLAST SOL. SOSTEN. DEL AGUA SL",
                "number": "1",
                "phoneBusiness": "985-792224",
                "postalCode": "33199",
                "region": "33",
                "street": "POL.IND.PRONI. CALLE D",
                "type": "WE"
            },
            {
                "StateOrProvince": "MERES-SIERO",
                "city": "MERES-SIERO",
                "countryCode": "ES",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "fax": "985793802",
                "id": "0000372156",
                "name": "SANIPLAST SOL. SOSTEN. DEL AGUA SL",
                "number": "1",
                "phoneBusiness": "985-792224",
                "postalCode": "33199",
                "region": "33",
                "street": "POL.IND.PRONI. CALLE D",
                "type": "AG"
            },
            {
                "StateOrProvince": "MERES-SIERO",
                "city": "MERES-SIERO",
                "countryCode": "ES",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "fax": "985793802",
                "id": "0000372156",
                "name": "SANIPLAST SOL. SOSTEN. DEL AGUA SL",
                "number": "1",
                "phoneBusiness": "985-792224",
                "postalCode": "33199",
                "region": "33",
                "street": "POL.IND.PRONI. CALLE D",
                "type": "RE"
            },
            {
                "StateOrProvince": "MERES-SIERO",
                "city": "MERES-SIERO",
                "countryCode": "ES",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "fax": "985793802",
                "id": "0000372156",
                "name": "SANIPLAST SOL. SOSTEN. DEL AGUA SL",
                "number": "1",
                "phoneBusiness": "985-792224",
                "postalCode": "33199",
                "region": "33",
                "street": "POL.IND.PRONI. CALLE D",
                "type": "RG"
            },
            {
                "StateOrProvince": "MERES-SIERO",
                "city": "MERES-SIERO",
                "countryCode": "ES",
                "customerNumber": "0000100001",
                "fax": "985793802",
                "id": "0000372156",
                "name": "SANIPLAST SOL. SOSTEN. DEL AGUA SL",
                "number": "1",
                "phoneBusiness": "985-792224",
                "postalCode": "33199",
                "region": "33",
                "street": "POL.IND.PRONI. CALLE D",
                "type": "ZV"
            }
        ],
        "email1": "JUANJOSE.GONZALEZ@SANIPLAST.ES",
        "entityCode": "ES01",
        "fax": "985793802",
        "phone1": "985-792224",
        "phone2": "985791154ISABEL",
        "termsofPayment": "Z037"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body)
if(json.CustomerMaster instanceof List){
    json.CustomerMaster.each{
        it.allPersons?.each{it.remove("customerNumber")}
        it.allAddresses?.each{it.remove("customerNumber")}
    }
}else{
    json.CustomerMaster?.allPersons?.each{it.remove("customerNumber")}
    json.CustomerMaster?.allAddresses?.each{it.remove("customerNumber")}
}
```

with ternary operator

```
( json.CustomerMaster instanceof List ? json.CustomerMaster : [json.CustomerMaster] ).each{
    it?.allPersons?.each{it.remove("customerNumber")}
    it?.allAddresses?.each{it.remove("customerNumber")}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it does work when the customerMaster is a map. however, it fails when customerMaster is an array.  Paylaod could either contain a map or an array''' {
    "CustomerMaster": [
        {
            "activitySector": "01",
            "allAddresses": [], "allPerons":[] } ] }'''

Comment: add type check for this case

Comment: normally you should mark the answer as "useful / accepted"

Comment: i get this error now java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.remove() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [customerNumber]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String)

Comment: it means that "allPersons" or "allAddresses" is a string or array of strings and there is no method "remove" for a string type.